# two computers with united CPU and memory resources?

Tags: memory, cpu, computer-architecture

is it possible?:) it wold be interesting, when given cheap chineese netbook and cheap chineese tablet, setup for example ubuntu to both of them, then le wild magic happens and viola - we have one mighty computer with more CPU cores, united RAM and video-card from the tablet:)

Comment: You could build a [cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_%28computing%29), but that's generally not going to be running any user-friendly interface

Comment: People make clusters out of cheap components all the time. See http://blog.afkham.org/2013/01/raspberry-pi-control-center.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining different independent computers is possible. The supercomputer [Titan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(supercomputer)), e.g., is composed of 18,688 different nodes; each node has its own CPU, GPU and RAM.

The problem lies in the specific details of *le wild magic*. You need a [distributed operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_operating_system) (Titan uses [UNICOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cray_Linux_Environment)) and – as far as I know – there are no desktop versions.

But suppose you have a distributed OS in some popular Linux flavor and you actually combine the computing power of a netbook and a tablet. What have you gained?

Two slow CPUs won't be much faster than one for most tasks, since most actions you can perform with a netbook aren't very parallelizable. The system memory of each device will only be available to that CPU (making two 4 core CPUs very different from one 8 core CPU). You're also going to be able to use only one GPU for video output.

Answer (score 1):

No. If we could make computers twice as fast for just double the cost, we already would.

Comment: Not really an answer for not really a question.

Comment: How is it not really an answer?

Comment: I was going through the Low Quality review task which flagged this answer. I didn't think it should be deleted but felt compelled to comment. Seemed like a flippant comment rather than an answer to the question.

Comment: Added a "No", should qualify as an answer now :).

Comment: @BradPatton: It is an accurate and precise answer. It explains what would be the case if the answer was "yes" and it's quite clear that's not the case.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I know a lot of time has passed since this question was asked, but it's still worth pointing out that the principle described by the OP is what's known as a cluster computer, and is in fact the exact technology which powers Google, Twitter, and the vast majority of Internet giants today. Admittedly, a cluster computer is neither as fast as the sum of its parts, nor as cost-effective to maintain, but neither of those were points brought up by the OP. Please be advised that this answer, as it stands today, is incomplete if not flat out wrong.

Comment: @ChefCyanide We design and build clusters precisely because the answer to this question is "no". If the answer was "yes", we wouldn't need all the complicated design that cluster computers have.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the question isn't "is it easy," but rather "is it possible" Therefore, the answer should be "yes, the memory and processing power of two computers can be untied together in the form of a cluster computer." Also, as someone with experience building small scale clusters, I can personally tell you that it really isn't as difficult with modern technology as you seem to suggest

Comment: @ChefCyanide Read the question again. It is not asking whether there's some complex, task-specific way to get more than one computer to cooperate. It's asking if there's a magic bullet to turn two slow computers into one faster one so that slow computers people have lying around can be just faster.

Answer (score 0):

I know a lot of time has passed since this question was asked, but it is worth pointing out that this can in fact be mostly accomplished using modern cluster computing technologies.

Although (as mentioned by @ernie in the comments) these do not typically have user friendly interfaces (most don't have a GUI at all), they are very powerful once you learn how to use them, and are currently used by many Internet giants like Google, Twitter, &c to power their gargantuan web applications.

If you have any interest in learning more about these sort of technologies or deploying one to your own infrastructure, I highly suggest taking a look at [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/), [DC/OS](https://dcos.io/), and [Apache Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/). These are each tools developed by Google LLC, Mesosphere Inc, and Twitter Inc respectively.